# Finding the owner of a shared folder Google Drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

After looking and finding for a shared folder that matches a given name, I need to know if that folder's creator/owner is a specific google account. How could I achieve that utilizing Google Drive's Objective-C SDK.

Here is my query that finds the shared folder given its name:

```
GTLQueryDrive *queryDrive = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
queryDrive.q = @"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false";

    [self.service executeQuery:queryDrive completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                              GTLDriveFileList *files,
                                                              NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            NSString *identifier = @"";
            for(GTLDriveFile *file in files.files)
            {
                NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:file.owners];
                NSLog(@"File Title:  %@ | ID: %@",file.name , file.identifier);
                if ([file.name isEqualToString:@"GIVEN FOLDER NAME"]) {
                    identifier = file.identifier;

                        //How to know if the found folder is owned by a specified email?

                    break;

                }
            }
            if ([identifier isEqualToString:@""]) {
                [UISpinningWheelController removeSpinningWheel:self.view];
                [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" andMessage:@"The required folder has not been shared with this Google account. Please contact the administrator."];
            }
        }
        else {
            [UISpinningWheelController removeSpinningWheel:self.view];
            [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" andMessage:[error localizedDescription]];
        }
    }];
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Try using [GTLDriveFile](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_drive_file.html#a83dd4c1f630a42761a4001e140640619) - owners to get the owners of the file. Then using [GTLDriveUser Class](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_drive_user.html#a50a14eda1046e1d96562f41d3c841165) to get the emailAddress in the properties. **NOTE**: This may not be present in certain contexts if the user has not made their email address visible to the requester. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Thanks for the suggestion; I tried it and come up with an empty array. How can I verify that the owner user has enabled their email address visible to the requester? And if they haven't where do I enable that?